# How can I create an installer (msi) in visual studio express 2010?

Tags: wpf, installation, visual-studio-express, advanced-installer

I have just finished creating a wpf application in visual studio express C# and need to create an installer file. This is going on just a couple of machines because it is a personal program for me. I have looked into [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/download.html) using the simple method but cannot figure out how to do that or if it can even create a wpf installer. I have also tried WIX with the same results.

Any tips for doing this?

Comment: The Simple project in Advanced Installer is pretty straightforward. Add the application files and build an MSI which installs them. What problems did you encounter?

Comment: The problem I am having is I don't now which folders and files to select. I selected the bin/release folder and the program does open but I am missing my images. I copied those manually and moved the files to have the same folder structure as the project folder. My images showed up, but is this all I need? I just did all of this by the way. Do I need anything else besides the images folder and the bin/release folder? Also, the Images folder is the only folder that I created.

Comment: That is pretty much it. To be sure, simply try making your application work on a clean machine and see which files and folders it needs. After that, simply add those files and folders in your installer.

Comment: I prefer WIX over Visual Studio's Installer but I am not sure if it works with Visual Studio Express: http://www.rhyous.com/2010/10/15/wix-creating-an-msi-and-deploying-your-first-file/

Cosmin Pivu gave you the rest of the info you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I start using WiX I worked with [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) and [HM NIS Edit](http://hmne.sourceforge.net/) which has a wizard to create simple installers.

Perhaps it can help you for your purposes.